# Redirect Standard Output/error to log file

Tags: shell, unix, redirect, tcsh

Looking for a way to redirect std error and std output to a log file in Tcsh shell.

Tried `./ShellFile.sh 2>&1 | pathToLogFile.log`
and got the error "Ambiguous output redirect"

Would appreciate any inputs.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For a start, it wouldn't be:

```
./ShellFile.sh 2>&1 | pathToLogFile.log
```

since that would try and pipe your output through the *executable file called pathToLogFile.log* rather than sending the output there.

You need:

```
./ShellFile.sh >& pathToLogFile.log
```

which redirects both standard output *and* error to the file.

Comment: thanks for the tip. But this overwrites the contents of pathToLogFile.log. What if we want to just append to the pathToLogFile.log?

Comment: @Sanjeev, then you would ask your _own_ question, with the specific requirements, rather than trying to ask a question in a comment field which very few people will see :-) That way, SO functions as intended with specific answers to specific questions. As a hint, you may want to look into `>>&`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Some answers didn't work for c shell and it did.

Comment: on raspberry pi this gave the error "Syntax error: Bad fd number"

Comment: @MarkCh, my first thought would be either that you're not *running* `tcsh` or the version under RaspPi is deficient somehow. It works fine in `tcsh` under Linux.

Comment: @paxdiablo my bad, didn't rtfq. I'll leave my comment there anyway, undoubtedly someone else will make the same mistake.

Answer (score 8):

On a side note, tee(1) may be of use if you want to see output both on the terminal *and* in a file.

```
  ./script 2>&1 | tee logfile.txt
```

Comment: In my testing this doesn't work in `tcsh`, but works in `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

From http://blog.elevenseconds.com/resources/shell-redirecting.html :

```
(cmd > /dev/tty) >& file1
```